# Problems defining options for bootstrap-combobox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, combobox, meteor

I'm have a heck of a time trying to get this [bootstrap-combobox](https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox) functioning properly in a Meteor App?

It says that you can "include an object containing options for the combobox". Because I can't get it to work without explicitly defining the options like this-

```
<template name="subAccounts">
<div id="sub_acct_1">
    Sub Acct 1: <select class="combobox" name="inline">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Item 1">Item 1</option>
        <option value="Item 2">Item 2</option>
        <option value="Item 2">Item 3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.combobox').combobox();
});
</script>
</template>
```

Will work but not display the "X" to delete a value entered manually.

This will not work at all but throws off no errors.

```
Template.subAccounts.subs = function() { 
    return subAccts.find();
};

<template name="subAccounts">
<div id="sub_acct_1">
    Sub Acct 1: <select class="combobox" name="inline">
        <option value=""></option>
        {{#each subs}}
            <option value="{{sub_name}}">{{sub_name}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.combobox').combobox();
});
</script>
</template>
```

and if I try this way I get nothing but errors when subAccount.subs is an array of values -

```
<template name="subAccounts">
<div id="sub_acct_1">
    Sub Acct 1: <select class="combobox" name="inline">
    </select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.combobox').combobox({item: subAccounts.subs});
});
</script>
</template>
```

If anyone has successfully used this any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "not display the "X" to delete a value entered manually"?

Comment: David, on the right side of the input field an "X" appears when you type in your own value. You should be able to click that to delete your value. Do you use this?

Comment: On the [demo site](http://bootstrap-combobox-test.herokuapp.com/?inline=) the X appears when any value is picked, not just a types in value?

Comment: When using static values I get the 'X' when I choose a value and clicking it removes it but typing in a value doesn't display the 'X'. Still haven't figured out how it is possible to populate the select dynamically, maybe it's not without working in bootstrap-combobox.js itself?